# unwind array field in document while keeping first fields

Tags: mongodb

here is the document I have.

```
[{ id:'786786', name: 'john', contacts:[{id:'1', text:'first contact'},{id:'1', text:'second contact'}]}]
```

Each array contains multiples contacts.

Do you know how to $unwind contacts array to geta document for each contact in contatcs :

```
[{name:'john', text:'first contact'},{name:'john', text:'second contact'}]
```

I tried $unwind and $map and it didn't worked

Thanks

[I finally did it !](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M_QrsmyBNat)
Thanks to [Tom Slabbaert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10770370/tom-slabbaert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `$unwind` suffices here:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$contacts"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$name",
      text: "$contacts.text"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SLncMwbKvjc)

Comment: That's what I did but strangely it returns a null array []...

Comment: Can you take a look at the playground example and tell me what's different from your data?

Comment: contact_cards is first an array with multiple objects following the structure I worte first

Comment: The structure I wrote first is actually a first $unwind. I tried to $unwind again with "$contact_cards.contacts" but it didn't worked

Comment: So can you edit in the original structure? it will be easier to help you then

Comment: I just did it now

Comment: it's just a different structure, try [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SLncMwbKvjc), i will also edit my answer

Comment: [I finally did it !](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M_QrsmyBNat) Thank you very much for your help